Correct way to build uwebsocket dependencies on windows 11 for MinGW?
My project structure is as follows
uwebsockets/   (git-submodule)
  - src
  - uSockets
    - boringssl
      - ...
    - lsquic
      - ...
    - ...
  - examples
    - ...
  - ...
entry.cpp
src/
  - ...
build.sh

Inside build.sh, I have a compile command that invokes g++ on entry.cpp
I know that to correctly build my project with its dependencies I need to include the proper include directories (using -I) and libraries (using -L and -l), so far it looks like this
/c/mingw64/bin/g++ -Wno-overflow -Wno-narrowing -fwrapv -O3 entry.cpp -Iuwebsockets/src -Iuwebsockets/uSockets/src -L$SEARCH -lzlib -luv -luSockets -o main
# $SEARCH will point to wherever the build output is

What is the easiest way to build and include the uwebsockets dependency (with its subdependencies) without:

Installing libraries system-wide
Installing visual studio or any of its components (I'd like to compile for MinGW)
Refactoring my project to use cmake

g++ is found in /mingw64/bin and my environment is Windows 11, x64
I've tried searching for prebuilt binaries to no avail
I know that uwebsockets is a header-only library, so here I am primarily talking about properly building all sub-dependencies, namely uv, zlib and usockets
None of the build resources I found in the uwebsockets repository helped at all in building (build.c, makefile, README.md, ...), the build script appears to be a stub and the makefile does not work for windows (cc: command not found)

As I commented in the staging ground (the comments are not transfered?), I'd start with installing MSYS2 (replacing your existing mingw). It does include cc.exe (I'm surprised your existing compiler doesn't), and some of your dependencies as prebuilt archives (at least uv and zlib).

@HolyBlackCat Yup, comments made in the staging ground remains in the staging ground!
